# Use NSFetchRequest + NSPredicate to check if an array inside a dictionary contains a value

Tags: swift, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

So I have an entity that has an attribute that is a dictionary like so: `[Int:[NSDate]]`

I would like to perform a fetch that only grabs entities that have a specific key who's value contains a specific date.

Is this possible?

The apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/) does not show anything that resembles this case.